# Instead of Delete trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to pass one validation DML statement on the trigger. Condition is below DML statement

```
select distinct t1.cid 
from table1 t1, table t2 
where t1.cid=t2.cid 
      and 
      t1.status<>'5'
```

if `table1.status` is  not 5, then trigger will block delete transaction.

```
CREATE TRIGGER LOAD_DROPID_DEL on WMWHSE2.table2
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
Begin
    declare @caseid VARCHAR(10)
    select @caseid = deleted.cid from deleted
    If exists(select * from table1 t1,table2 t2 where t1.cid=t2.cid AND t1.STATUS<>'5' AND t2.cid=@caseid)
    begin
        Rollback Transaction
        RAISERROR ('Deletions not allowed after loaded ', 16, 1) 
    end
end
```

Will the above trigger will give correct solution?

Answer (score 4):

An INSTEAD OF trigger is not the best solution here. An `INSTEAD OF` trigger performs no actions against the database unless explicitly done so in the trigger code. Your example will never delete rows regardless of the `STATUS` value because it contains no `DELETE` statement. The `ROLLBACK` is superfluous since no modifications were made.

Consider an `AFTER DELETE` trigger for this requirement. As with any trigger, multiple rows may be affected so it is important to handle such a case. Avoid using the `select @caseid` as that will identify only a single `cid` value even if different ones were deleted.

Here's an example of an after trigger for your need.

```
CREATE TRIGGER LOAD_DROPID_DEL on WMWHSE2.table2
FOR DELETE
AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted where deleted.STATUS <>'5')
BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Deletions not allowed after loaded ', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END;
GO
```